# changing id/URL slug in rails 3 app using mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Currently in my rails app, records are located at URLs like:

http://www.mysite.com/items/fecffe6aa299a6050274ed22

but instead I'd like them to be going to something like:

http://www.mysite.com/items/item-title-here

any ideas for how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using the [mongoid_slug gem](https://github.com/hakanensari/mongoid-slug): it lets you generate a URL slug or permalink based on one or more fields in a Mongoid model.

Here's their usage example:

```
## Set up a slug:
class Book
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Slug
    field :title
    slug :title
end

## Find a record by its slug:
# GET /books/a-thousand-plateaus
book = Book.find_by_slug params[:book_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

just modify the "show" function

For instance

> def show
>
> ```
> item= Item.where({name=>params[:id]}).first
> do something...
> ```
>
> end

Just put the function to get an object from your own id....